# Sort Excel row columns' data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have in Excel table five columns: A, B, C, D and E. Each of them keeps int.

[image]

I need to get columns sorted ascending. How can I do this?
There is hardcoded example.

[image]

Comment: and... are you having any specific difficulties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the [excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula)-tag, I would suggest to use [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-17da8222-7c82-42b2-961b-14c45384df07) like in A5 `=SMALL($A1:$E1,COLUMN())` and then copy the formula to the right (E5) and down (A7:E7)